# Cross compilation for RISC-V with GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, riscv

GCC has the capability to compile targeting RISC-V https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/RISC-V-Options.html but when I looked at how I can cross-compile for RISC-V, I saw a lot of tutorials about how to compile GCC with RISC-v support and then use it for cross-compilation.

Is there any documentation that shows how I can compile a simple application (say hello world) with just GCC and make a file and how I can extend it to more complex situations, such as compiling OpenCV for RISC-V?